# Read in two files and write to a third file with merged strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Given two text files, each line shows the absolute path of each image.

The first two lines of the first text file read

```
/home/picture/I10045.jpg
/home/picture/I10056.jpy
```

The first two lines of the second text file reads

```
Cat, Dog
Mouse, Mouse, Mouse
```

How is it that you would read in the two separate files and delete the duplicates of the second file. Then merge them together to make a third file.

Output in the third text file should read

```
/home/picture/I10045.jpg Cat, Dog
/home/picture/I10056.jpg Mouse
```

Comment: what's the error/problem that you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that in your current working directory `file1.txt` contains:

```
/home/picture/I10045.jpg
/home/picture/I10056.jpy
```

and `file2.txt` contains

```
Cat, Dog
Mouse, Mouse, Mouse
```

It also assumes that we don't care about the order of the elements in each line of `file2.txt` since it uses `set` to remove duplicates. If you need that order i'd consider using a `for` loop instead of a comprehension and manually building a list while checking membership with `in` or making some unconventional use of `OrderedDict`, there's some more details on how to do that stuff in here: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
    file1_lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in file1]
    file2_lines = [set(line.strip("\n").split(", ")) for line in file2]

with open("file3.txt", "w") as file3:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1_lines, file2_lines):
        print(line1, ", ".join(line2), file=file3)
```

The contents of `file3.txt`:

```
/home/picture/I10045.jpg Dog, Cat
/home/picture/I10056.jpy Mouse
```

An explanation of what's happening:

We open both input files using `with`, which is usually recommended.

We run a list comprehension on the open `file1` object which just removes the newlines from each line, this will help when we join the lines together later.

We run another list comprehension over our open `file2` object which removes newlines and then splits each line on commas into a `set`. This removes any duplicates and leaves us with a list of sets.

We open `file3.txt` for writing and use `zip` to allow us to iterate over both the lists we just made.
we use `join` to rebuild the lines in `file2.txt` with commas from the sets that are in `file2_lines`. We don't have to do anything special to the lines from `file1.txt`.

We use `print` with the `file=` argument to write to our file.. it's worth noting that this is `file=` won't work in python2 without importing `print_function` from `__future__`.. if you're using python2 you should probably just use `file3.write()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Function to remove the duplicates
def remove_dup(s):
    temp_s = s.split(',')       # Thinking that the second file only has the tags
    check = {}
    for i in temp_s:
        if i in check:
            check[i]+=1
        else:
            check[i]=1

    # Constructing the string
    return_string = ""
    for i in range(0,len(temp_s)):
        if check[temp_s[i]]==1 and i==0:
            return_string = return_string+temp_s[i]
        elif check[temp_s[i]]==1:
            return_string = return_string+", "+temp_s[i]

    return return_string

#Reading in the files
file1 = open('test1.txt','r')
text1 = [i.rstrip() for i in file1]

file2 = open('test2.txt','r')
dup_text2 = [i.rstrip() for i in file2]

# Removing duplicates
text2 = [remove_dup(i) for i in dup_text2]

# Adding the content
text3 = [text1[i]+" "+text2[i] for i in range(0,len(text1))]

# Writing to the file
with open('test3.txt','w') as f:
    for line in text3:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
with open('file3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        file2lines = file2.readlines()
        for line in file1 :
            outfile.write(line.replace('\n', '').strip() + ' ' + str(set(file2lines[i].replace('\n', '').replace(', ', ',').split(','))) + '\n')
            i=i+1
```

It opens both files, then uses file1 as the main for loop. Most of the code is the text clean up (removing spaces, new lines etc) and then I used split to convert the animals into a list, and then used set to eliminate duplicates. Then I converted it back to a string.